# How should the behaviour of an auth server after logout?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am doing an evaluation of products and I am see different implementations. So I am wondering which one is right.

Library used: [manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc)

Example #1:

I tried integrating with Keycloak.

The behaviour of logout, is as follows:

- Invalidate session token.
- Sign out of idp to prevent any other SSO from the browser.

Example #2:

I integrated my app to AWS Cognito.

The behaviour of logout, is as follows

- Does not invalidate session token.
- Still allows to sign so long as the token is valid.

Could I ask which of these behaviour are correct? Or is it based on what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito has vendor specific logout endpoints so I think you need to override default behaviour.

See [Step 12 of my write up](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/08/how-to-run-the-react-js-spa) and the [coded solution](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/utilities/customLogoutManager.ts) which explains how I did this with the OIDC Client library.

Out of interest you can run my deployed SPA on [this page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/).

Answer (score 0):

We need to manually call the Cognito logout endpoint. Here's the code to use with angular-auth-odic client

```
logout() {
  // Revoke from library sessions
  this.oidcSecurityService.logoffAndRevokeTokens()
  this.oidcSecurityService.logoff();
  
  //set issuer url and logut url
  const stsServer = `${environment.issuer}`;
  const logoutUrl = `${window.location.origin}/`;

  //get open id configuration from cognito
  this.http.get<OpenIdConfigParams>(stsServer+"/.well-known/openid-configuration")
  .subscribe((openIdConfigParams) => {
    // call logout url with the browser redirection
    const url = openIdConfigParams.authorization_endpoint.replace("oauth2/authorize", "");
    window.location.href = url+`logout?client_id=${environment.clientId}&logout_uri=${logoutUrl}`;
  })
  return;
}
```